# scikit's RBM pseudo likelihood calculation

Tags: scikit-learn, restricted-boltzmann-machine, likelihood

According to scikit-learn's documentation given [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.html#sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.score_samples), the pseudo likelihood is calculated by;

Computing the free energy on X, then on a randomly corrupted version of X, and returns the log of the logistic function of the difference.

I'm trying to understand why is pseudo likelihood implemented like this. What was the motivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an approximation of the pseudolikelihood, as defined, e.g., in Equation (18.20) in Goodfellow et al.'s "Deep Learning" (c.f. http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/partition.html).

In particular, instead of summing over all visible variables, the scikit variant picks "only" one at random. It is obvious that this gives a drastic performance gain (when the number of visible units is large).  Regarding the precision (that is how close it is to the true pseudolikelihood), I have no answer...

It is worth reading the remaining of the above chapter, which gives useful references regarding the randomised approximation.